# QT Mobile: How to Play .swf file in QT Mobile Application

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qt-events

How to Play .swf file in QT mobile Application. ?

As I have applied below two 
ui->webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled,true); 
ui->webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled,true);

But i could not play still .swf file?

Answer (score 1):

Which platform are you on? Netscape plugin support only works on the desktop, and the plugins need to reside in specific places to work, see http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support for details.

Comment: I am developing Nokia Application, for that i am using QT SDK 4.7.

Comment: "Nokia" is not a platform, but assuming you mean Symbian, I'm afraid Qt does not support plugins there. If you just want to play an swf, you won't need an SWF view, you can do that with the Symbian C++ snippets from http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_make_Flash_launcher_with_Symbian_C++.

Comment: We are not using Symbian, developing application in QT Creator with CPP Platform.

Comment: CPP or C++ is not a platform either, it's a programming language that happens to be quite universal. Which Operating Systems are you targeting (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X)? And what do you mean by "I am developing Nokia Application"? You mean you are (contractually) developing an application _for_ Nokia? If you don't ask clearly, you  won't get clear answers.